# Qual a diferença entre querySelectorAll() e getElementsByClassName()

Tags: javascript, dom

Aparentemente essas duas funções são parecidas, qual é mais performática? Qual deveria usar? Qual a diferença entre as duas?

*document.querySelectorAll()*

```js
function funDOM() {
    var x = document.querySelectorAll(".example");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
<body onload="funDOM()">
    <div>
        Duvidas <span class="example">vermelhas</span>
    
    </div>
    <p class="example">vermelho</p>
    
    
</body>
</html>
```

*document.getElementsByClassName()*

```js
function funDOM() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("example");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
<body onload="funDOM()">
    <div>
        Duvidas <span class="example">vermelhas</span>
    
    </div>
    <p class="example">vermelho</p>
    
    
</body>
</html>
```

Desde já obrigado por suas considerações.

Comment: A diferença é que `querySelectorAll` pode ser usado para outros seletores que não de classe apenas. E mesmo sendo de classe consegue especificar hierarquia por exemplo utilizando espaço ou `>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` retorna elementos DOM ao vivo e qualquer alteração subsequente feita a esses elementos DOM será refletida na lista.

`querySelectorAll` não retorna elementos DOM ao vivo. Alterações subsequentes na estrutura do documento não serão refletidas no objeto NodeList retornado. O elemento basicamente contem uma lista de nós presentes no documento no momento que foi criado.

Suponha que você tem uma classe chamado `bg-blue` e essa classe é usada em 5 elementos diferentes. Ao fazer

```
var myElem = documento.getElementsByClassName("bg-blue");
```

A variável myElem teria os 5 elementos que contem a classe. Para acessar um elemento específico você poderia fazer da seguinte forma.

```
var myElem = documento.getElementsByClassName("bg-blue")[0];
```

Dessa forma ele vai retornar o primeiro elemento do DOM com a classe bg-blue

Comment: As duas não retornam um NodeList com todos os elementos?

Comment: Ao fazer uma modificação da classe usando o getElementsByClassName a nodeList diminue, mas no querySelectorAll não.

Answer (score 2):

As principais diferenças são basicamente duas:

- [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) só faz buscas pelo nome da classe, enquanto [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) faz buscas por qualquer seletor válido - isso inclui buscar pelo `id`, pelo nome da *tag*, por valores dos atributos, e [muitas outras opções descritas na documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)
- `getElementsByClassName` retorna uma lista "viva" que é atualizada conforme o DOM é alterado, enquanto `querySelectorAll` retorna uma lista "fixa" que não muda

Exemplo:

```js
// buscar por elementos com a classe "abc"
let abcLiveList = document.getElementsByClassName('abc');
console.log('getElementsByClassName: ');
for (const e of abcLiveList) {
    console.log(`- ${e.innerText}`);
}
let abcFixedList = document.querySelectorAll('.abc');
console.log('querySelectorAll: ');
for (const e of abcFixedList) {
    console.log(`- ${e.innerText}`);
}

// atualizando o DOM (adicionar novo elemento)
let span = document.createElement('span');
span.classList.add('abc');
span.innerHTML = 'novo';
document.body.appendChild(span);

console.log('getElementsByClassName (atualizado com o novo elemento): ');
for (const e of abcLiveList) {
    console.log(`- ${e.innerText}`);
}
console.log('querySelectorAll (não é atualizado com o novo elemento): ');
for (const e of abcFixedList) {
    console.log(`- ${e.innerText}`);
}
```

```html
<div class="abc">olá</div>
<p class="abc">tudo bem?</p>
<p>blá</p>
```

Repare que em `getElementsByClassName('abc')` eu passei o nome da classe `'abc'`, já em `querySelectorAll('.abc')` o nome da classe precisou de um ponto antes (`'.abc'`), pois esta é a [sintaxe de seletores para buscar por um nome de classe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors).

Veja também que a lista retornada por `getElementsByClassName` muda conforme o DOM é alterado: ao adicionar um novo elemento com a classe "abc", este passa a fazer parte da lista automaticamente. Já a lista retornada por `querySelectorAll` não muda, independente das mudanças feitas no DOM (se eu quisesse ter o novo elemento, precisaria fazer uma nova busca).

---

> *Qual deveria usar?*

Depende do que você precisa. Você quer que a lista seja atualizada conforme o DOM é alterado? Quer buscar somente pelo nome da classe ou usar algum critério mais complexo? (como por exemplo, somente as tags `div` com a classe "abc" - nesse caso, `querySelectorAll` seria o mais indicado) - e por aí vai. Não tem resposta certa, depende da necessidade.

Quanto a ser mais performático, há testes que dizem que [`querySelectorAll` é mais lento](https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/4076/0/queryselectorall-vs-getelementsbyclassname#latest_results_block), mas isso não deveria ser o único critério. Se for uma página "muito grande" com várias buscas sendo feitas, pode ser que haja alguma demora perceptível, mas de qualquer forma, desempenho é algo que deve ser testado caso a caso, você não deveria escolher usar um ou outro antes de testar (primeiro escolha o que faz mais sentido, e se você detectar que essa é a causa da performance ruim, aí você muda).