# Qual a diferença entre document.querySelector e getElementsByTagName?

Tags: javascript, dom, html-tags

Gostaria de saber as diferenças no uso desses dois comandos, pois para min que estou no inicio do estudo muito parecidas e até mesmo iguais em alguns momentos, mas tendo nomenclaturas diferentes deve-se ter diferenças entre as duas.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Qual a diferença entre querySelectorAll() e getElementsByClassName()](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/270954/qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-queryselectorall-e-getelementsbyclassname)

Comment: São diferentes da minha pergunta.

Comment: @BrunoSuarez da uma olhada na minha resposta ;)

Answer (score 5):

Vou explicar um por um e depois a diferença entre eles.

`document.querySelector()`:
Retorna apenas o **primeiro** elemento com as propriedades `CSS` inseridas como parâmetro e só pode ser utilizado no escopo do `document`. Exemplo:

```js
console.log("Retorna apenas o primeiro elemento que deu match:")
console.log(document.querySelector("table"))
```

```html
<table id="table-01">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="table-02">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

`Element.getElementsByTagName()`:
É uma função da classe [`object`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ex_dom.asp) que seleciona **todos os elementos** contidos no objeto que está sendo utilizado como construtor. Ou seja retorna uma coleção de objetos.
Exemplo:

```js
var table1 = document.getElementById("table-01");

console.log("Retorna TODOS os td's dentro de document")
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("td"));

console.log("Retorna TODOS os td's dentro do objeto table1")
console.log(table1.getElementsByTagName("td"));
```

```html
<table id="table-01">
  <tr>
    <td>casa</td>
    <td>prédio</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="table-02">
  <tr>
    <td>rua</td>
    <td>avenida</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

A diferença é:

`document.querySelector()` retorna **apenas um objeto** através de um **seletor CSS**.
`Element.getElementsByTagName()` retorna **uma coleção de objetos** através das tags html.

Se você quiser utilizar o `document.querySelector()` e retornar uma coleção, existe o comando [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) que recebe o mesmo parâmetro porém retorna coleções.

Fontes:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Comment: Muito obrigado pela explicação Leonardo!

Comment: @BrunoSuarez se ajudou, nao esquece de marcar como a resposta correta !